# How to insert a div in PHP properly?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm doing a school project for university. And i'd like to format the images which I already have in my css file, and when I declare with a div putting a echo behind it it doesn't work, what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Here it's a print]

Comment: Why is there a closing tag after the while loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also what does this have to do with [tag:sql-server]? You're clearly using the MySQLI Library in your code, which doesn't work with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **"best"** way (in my opinion) to prevent "spaghetti" style is to differentiate php and html like:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result){
?>
  <div class='imagem'>
    <img src="<?php echo $row['logo'];?>" width="180px">
  </div>
<?php
}
```

Side note: Next time if your question have a code use the tools `<>` (html/js) or `{}` (php and others lang)

Comment: Ahhhh it worked, It's a simple thing but I really get confusing, opening/ending html and php tags... It's my first year at uni learning web development and 2nd semester is a pain in the ass with the database stuff haha! Thank you very much for this silly problem of mine.